# Can higher version of .NET Framework be used for project targetting lower version?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, backwards-compatibility, .net-framework-version

If a `Visual Studio` solution contains projects targetting different versions of the `.NET` Framework, can the application be distributed with just the higher version of the `.NET` Framework?

Comment: Too vague.  You may well need an `<supportedRuntime>` element in the app.exe.config file.  Required for example to run on v4.x when the target was < 4.0.  And you of course need to test it so you'll find this out quick enough.

Answer (score 2):

> If a Visual Studio solution contains projects targetting different versions of the .NET Framework, can the application be distributed just with the higher version of the .NET Framework?

In general, yes.  The application's version of the framework will (typically) be used.

The one exception is if you're using COM - with COM, it's possible to have 2 versions of the common language runtimed loaded at once, which could require having both versions on the target system.

However, if it's a pure .NET/managed application, the executable's CLR version will be used, and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, it depends.

As long as your app is only using common features that do not have "Breaking Changes" in the new version, then in general this is possible...

Each release of the .NET framework will list "Breaking Changes" that list things that have changed since the last version that break compatibility.

Another potential issue is that Some versions of the framework do "in-place" upgrades.  For instance, if you have an app that targets .net 4.0, and you install .net 4.5 on the same box, even if it already had 4.0 on it, then it will upgrade certain framework components to 4.5, such as ASP.NET and WPF.

This means that even apps that target 4.0 will run on the 4.5 framework assembly.

Comment: Should add that obsolete APIs might be removed one day (but so far Microsoft hasn't done yet).